# After implement Security Patch SUPEE 8788v2 , site is giving 404 ERROR

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788

I am working on  **Magento 1.9.2.1.** I have uploaded the Patch files of **SUPEE 8788** on the root of the website. I have also **deleted the below listed files**:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
```

also checked for the following **files that have been modified**:

```
/js/mage/adminhtml/uploader/instance.js  contain "fustyFlowFactory"
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/boxes.css  contain "background:url(images/blank.gif) repeat;"
```

But still this **patch failed in Magento Security scan**.

After that i implemented 8788v2 and my site starts giving 404 ERROR.
I used the below link to revert 8788 and implement 8788v2.

```
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html
```

Please guide me to implement the patch.

Comment: did you apply SUPEE-8788v2?

Comment: No, I have applied SUPEE-8788-1.9.2.1

Comment: You need to apply v2 to pass the Magento security test https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788-without-ssh/

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews I have applied the v2 and my site starts giving Error 404.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check out that **old patches** had been installed correctly or not. In magento **patches depend on the other older patches**, so you need to check which patches have been install in your site using any of the following methods.

https://www.magebees.com/how-to-install-magento-security-patch-supee-8788/

I hope it will help you.